# Using Loaded Trigger in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, command, mvvm-light

When you use MVVM Light in WPF or UWP you can use triggers like whne you navigate to a page use the trigger event Load.

Like this:

```
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Loaded">
                <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LoadedCommand}" />
            </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

And this are the namespaces:

```
xmlns:i="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
```

But how can you do this in `Xamarin.Forms`? Is it the same? I can't find a example.

UPDATE

My xaml page:

Reference to EventToCommandBehavior:

```
xmlns:behaviors="clr-namespace:XamarinTest.Behaviors"

<ContentPage.Behaviors>
        <behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="OnAppearing"
                                          Command="{Binding LoadedCommand}" />
</ContentPage.Behaviors>
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
               HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

And this is my ViewModel:

```
public RelayCommand LoadedCommand { get; }

public UserMainViewModel()
{
    LoadedCommand = new RelayCommand(LoadData);
}

private async void LoadData()
{
    //...
}
```

And the binding between the xaml Page and the ViewModel is like this in Page1.xaml.cs:

```
public Page1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = App.Locator.UserMainViewModel;
}
```

Error:

```
 at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00017] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.DoInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x0007a] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo.Invoke (System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at MyProject.Services.NavigationService.NavigateTo (System.String pageKey, System.Object parameter) [0x000e8] in C:\Projects\MyProject\MyProject\MyProject\Services\NavigationService.cs:89 
  at MyProject.Services.NavigationService.NavigateTo (System.String pageKey) [0x00001] in C:\Projects\MyProject\MyProject\MyProject\Services\NavigationService.cs:42 
  at MyProject.ViewModels.LoginViewModel.Login () [0x00002] in C:\Projects\MyProject\MyProject\MyProject\ViewModels\LoginViewModel.cs:25
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to use EventToCommandBehavior as described here https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/behaviors/reusable/event-to-command-behavior/

And implement the following xaml in your page:
OnAppearing exists only on pages. (No Loaded event)

```
<ContentPage.Behaviors>
   <local:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="Appearing" Command="{Binding LoadedCommand}" />
<ContentPage.Behaviors>
```

Comment: I created the BehaviorBase.cs and EventToCommandBehavior.cs but I get this message 'bindable not an instance of AssociatedType'

Comment: In your xaml? Your Binding is probably incorrect. Post some code If you want help

Comment: Updated the question with what I have so far.

Comment: Where the error occurs? On xaml side? On which property? At runtime or during compilation?

Comment: On XAML side , when I comment the code I get no error. At runtime when I push the button to go the the page where I use the OnAppearing event.

Comment: I have no idea I followed your link and did everything they said :o

Comment: Try to modify your viewModel code with:    public Command LoadedCommand { get; }

public UserMainViewModel()
{
    LoadedCommand = new Command(LoadData);
}

private void LoadData(object)
{
    //...
}

Comment: Can you post your entire viewModel? Something must be incorrect somewhere else.

Comment: Hello euhm I changed public class EventToCommandBehavior : BehaviorBase<View> to public class EventToCommandBehavior : BehaviorBase<VisualElement> and now it works

Comment: The EventName needs to be "Appearing" instead of "OnAppearing". See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.page.appearing?view=xamarin-forms.